# Pattern/Matcher vs String.split() for the same regex

Tags: java, regex

Why does Pattern/Matcher work with `(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)` but `String.split()` doesn't ?

For example:

```
String line = "1A2B";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
System.out.println(m.groupCount());

while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints :

```
2
1A
2B
```

But :

```
    String line = "1A2B";
    String [] arrayOfStrings = line.split("(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
    System.out.println(arrayOfStrings.length);

    for(String elem: arrayOfStrings){
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
```

Prints only:

```
0
```

Comment: The regex in the case of `split` is a delimiter whereas in the case of matcher it's a "pattern" used to match your expression of choice...

Comment: You want to split according to what?

Comment: Just split into groups of (number+letter). But why can't I use the same regex with String.split() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `.split(String regex)` uses the regular expression to mark where to break the string. So, in your case, if you have `1A2B£$%^&` it will print 1 string: `£$%^&` because it will split at `1A` and then again at `2B`, however, since those return empty groups, they are omitted and you are left with just `£$%^&`.

On the other hand, the regular expression does is that it matches the strings and puts them into groups. These groups can then be accessed at a later stage as you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it didnt work**

Because the spit would consume those characters and there is no character left to be in the output list

**Solution**

Not perfect but look aheads will help you

```
String line = "1A2B";
String [] arrayOfStrings = line.split("(?=\\d+[a-zA-Z]+)");
System.out.println(arrayOfStrings.length);

for(String elem: arrayOfStrings){
    System.out.println(elem);
```

will give output as

```
3

1A
2B
```

Not perfect becuase the look ahead will be true at the start of the string, thus creating an empty string in the output list at index 0. In the example you can see that the length is 3 where as we expect 2

Comment: Oops sorry my bad. Thanks :)